# Error: set object doesn't support indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x

It is showing an error in this statement:

```
result.append(function(*[subsequent[i] for subsequent in sequences]))
```

Comment: That exception message suggests that `subsequent` is a `set` object at some point during your list comprehension. A `set` is an iterable container, but not a sequence. I'd double check that `sequences` contains the objects that you intend. I can't really offer a solution beyond this, as you've supplied so little detail in your question.

Comment: Python thinks `subsequent` is a [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets). Sets do not support iteration as they are an unordered collection. You would need to first cast it to a list.

Comment: @Alan I think you meant indexing. Sets support iteration just like any other collection.

Comment: As others said (and Python interpreter as well), `subsequent[i]` is not valid if `subsequent` is a `set`. There is nothing more we can tell you than what Python is already telling you if you don't give some context, i.e. your input, the goal you are trying to achieve and desired output. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).